# peer to peer socket based chat python and ios

Tags: python, tcp

I successfully created a simple chat server using this tutorial of reywenderlich
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/

Code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "data is ", data
        a = data.split(':')
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]

            msg = ""
            if command == "iam":
                self.name = content
                msg = self.name + " has joined"

            elif command == "msg":
                msg = self.name + ": " + content

            print msg

            for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(79, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Basically the whole tutorial shows a chat implementation where user join a specific chat room and chat with each other real-time. But my client wants a peer-to-peer chat mechanism where the user choose a specific user to chat with so I really don't have any idea to make it to reality. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a p2p connection you need to create a protocol that would allow one of the sides to know the IP address and a listening port of the other side, and the other side to listen on a specific port.

This can be done by creating a request to the chat server to start a p2p connection. The chat server will then send the other client a message asking for permission and after a positive response which should include the listening port transfer that information to the initiating party along with the IP address of his peer.

At this point the initiating client should create a TCP connection to the other party and from the moment the connection is established you can transfer whatever data you'd like.

A simple way to do that would be to allow ASCII-escaped commands to the chat server, for instance `/p2p <NICKNAME>`  which would tell the server that the client wants to start a p2p connection. The server will then be able to send something like `/p2p-request from <NICKNAME>` to the requested chatter and he could respond with something like `/p2p-accept <port>` or `/p2p-reject <reason>`. If the response was `/p2p-accept` the server can then return to the originating client with something line `/p2p-accepted <IP> <port>`.

Along with the `/p2p-accept` the client will need to create a listening socket:

```
p2p_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
p2p_socket.bind(('', port))
p2p_socket.listen(1)
p2p_chat, p2p_address = p2p_socket.accpet()
```

The initiating party will need to connect to this socket:

```
p2p_chat = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
p2p_chat.connect((ip, port))
```

And once connection is established `send()` and `recv()` can be used to send data between the clients.

This can, of course, be written over Twisted, but I'm not well versed in it so I'd rather stick to the low APIs.

Comment: what do you mean by those low APIs? are you referring to the native implementation of python itself? or is there some ready-made api available in the internet. in any case, is there anything you can recommend ?

Comment: It's the pythons socket API (`import socket`). It's just OS level API so it's the lowest possible API to deal with sockets. No wrappers - and therefore all the `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM`.
The code snippets I posted should work, but it'll need some integration into the Twisted code that you showed above (though I suppose that registering the `.fileno()` of the socket objects into the Twisted reactor should not pose too much of a problem).

Comment: this p2p connection instance for every user pair can be done within the same port? with this, we can say that on one port you can create different instance that can handle different request-accept protocols on each users?

Comment: It will require a more complex Client software, but it's possible - just place `p2p_socket` into the reactor and `accept` any request that comes, after a validation that it's approved.

Comment: let's say I am using iOS as the client. how can the server create another instance of a chat session and how can the server knows from whom and to whom the data will be sent

Comment: p2p connection means a connection between the clients that doesn't go through the server. The server is the means by which the 2 clients can find each other and negotiate a session.
Once one of the sides has a listening socket and the other has the IP and port to connect to, the server is out of the picture.
As for iOS - do you mean a specific APP or the general platform? Because if you're not writing the client yourself this can't work unless the client supports this.

Comment: Is it possible all you need is a "private" chat feature? like a room for only 2 specific users? It's not called p2p.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40426/discussion-between-john-micah-fernandez-miguel-and-immortal)